# Import error raised even though library is not required on worker nodes

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm writing a custom library for my PySpark application, and it needs to do a little pre-processing using the Pandas library on some CSV files. The pre-processing is "supposed" (well, that's what I think) to be done on the driver node since the input file itself is stored in the driver and not in HDFS. However, after I add the library as a package using the `addPyFile` function, import the required methods and execute the function, it raises an `ImportError`.

The package structure is like this

```sh
module
|- __init__.py
|- module_1.py
|- module_2.py
|- sub_module_1
   |- __init__.py
   |- sub_mod_1.py
|- ...
```

What I do in my Python runner script is

```py
spark = SparkSession.builder.enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
spark.sparkContext.addPyFile("module.zip")

from module import module_1

module_1.func(spark, configs) # Exception raised here
```

In `module_1.py`, I have

```py
import pandas as pd
from sub_module_1 import sub_mod_1

def func(spark, configs):

    input_local_file = configs.get("SOME_SECTION", "local_file")
    input_hdfs_file = configs.get("SOME_SECTION", "hdfs_file")
    output_hdfs_destination = configs.get("SOME_SECTION", "hdfs_dest")

    # Reads input file
    lf_pdf = pd.read_csv(input_local_file)
    # Convert pandas dataframe to dictionary object
    transformed_dict = to_dictionary(lf_pdf)
    # Log printed

    # Writes to hdfs, wraps a mapPartitions function
    another_method(transformed_dict, input_hdfs_file, output_hdfs_destination)
```

So, does this mean that even though I don't actually use Pandas in the worker nodes, as long as the package requires the module and is distributed via the `addPyFile` option, it will require the Pandas library to be installed in the workers as well? The thing is, `module_2` does almost the exact same thing, except that the Pandas dataframe is converted to a Spark dataframe instead but it doesn't raise the same Exception.

The full error message is:

```sh
WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 48.2 in stage 4.0 (TID 167, somewhere.org, executor 35): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.2.0.cloudera1-1.cdh5.12.0.p0.142354/lib/spark2/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 166, in main
    func, profiler, deserializer, serializer = read_command(pickleSer, infile)
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.2.0.cloudera1-1.cdh5.12.0.p0.142354/lib/spark2/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 57, in read_command
    command = serializer.loads(command.value)
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.2.0.cloudera1-1.cdh5.12.0.p0.142354/lib/spark2/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 454, in loads
    return pickle.loads(obj)
  File "./module.zip/module/module_1.py", line 15, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pandas

        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:193)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:234)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:152)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

**EDIT:** I've also been logging the steps in my application, and the point at which this error is raised is after all the pre-processing is completed, which is why I'm not sure why it's even occurring since Pandas is never used again.

Comment: Can you give us the full error message, including stack trace?

Comment: @Steve Added to the question details.

Comment: An "import" statement in Python is a command to import something regardless if it is needed later. When a module is imported, it is executed. If it in turn contains an "import" at top level, this is executed as well.

Comment: @MichaelButscher: But `module_2` in the same library does not raise the same error even though both use Pandas for pre-processing.

Comment: Has it also an "import pandas..." at the top level (outside of any function)?

Comment: @MichaelButscher Yes, it does, right at the top of the module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason for the inconsistency - only the modules which used the `mapPartitions` method exhibited the issue. I just did this

```py
try:
    import pandas
except:
    pass
```

since the library isn't used in the worker nodes at all.